# How to use routes in Vue.js (typescript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I juste started a new project with Vue.js, long time I didn't use it, it changed a lot.
Tried to add a route in my `src/router/index.ts` (showed below), i go to localhost:8080 to see my beautiful `Helloworld.vue` component, and I see the content of my `Simulator.vue` that is "Yooood".

How can it be possible ? Since the basepath of my app accessing by "/" is the HelloWorld.vue component, with only a "Hello World" text...

When i'm trying to access the `/simulator` using a `<router-link to="/simulator">Go to Simulator</router-link>` I got the same content...

I am a bit confused.... This is my files below.

router/index.ts

```ts
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Simulator from "@/components/Simulator.vue";
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: HelloWorld
  },
  {
    path: '/simulator',
    name: 'Simulator',
    component: Simulator
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

So this is my Simulator.vue :

```html
    <template>
        <div class="hello">
            Yooood
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
        import {Vue} from "vue-property-decorator";
    
        export default class Simulator extends Vue {
    
            mounted() {
                console.log('mounted');
            }
        }
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
    
    </style>
```

And my HelloWorld.vue

```html
    <template>
      <p>
        Hello World
      </p>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    
    @Component
    export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
      @Prop() private msg!: string;
    }
    </script>
    
    <!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
    <style scoped>
    h3 {
      margin: 40px 0 0;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 10px;
    }
    a {
      color: #42b983;
    }
    </style>
```

My App.vue

```html
    <template>
      <div id="app">
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import {Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    
    export default class App extends Vue {}
    </script>
    
    <style>
    #app {
      font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      text-align: center;
      color: #2c3e50;
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: It's one thing to miss the `<router-view>` component from `App.vue` but the behaviour that displays `Yood` is in-explicable. I don't understand why it shows one over the other. It shouldn't show anything with the absence of the `<router-view>` component.

Comment: To test a theory, could you remove the `@component` decorator from this line `export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {` which currently has it, and place it on top of this line ` export default class Simulator extends Vue {` and see what happens. Check If it displays `Hello World`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the router-view component. According to the vue-router [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#aria-current-value),

> *The `<router-view>` component is a functional component that renders the
> matched component for the given path*

#### APP.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view> // add router view component
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I added it and removed the @Component from HelloWorld component and added it to Simulator.
Now on the path `/` it show the good component, but when I click on my :

`<router-link to="/simulator">Go to Simulator</router-link>`

It changes the url but doesn't show the simulator component :(

Comment: The `@Component` should be on both of them, @Thibault Dumas. That defines the component. Sorry, in the comments, I wasn't clear. I wanted you to remove one and change it to the other to test something (without adding the `<router-view/> component). I wanted to understand why it was showing anything without the `<router-view/>` component.

Comment: I am happy to help. Could you please accept my answer ? I also posted something above. I am interested to know why it printed `Yooo` in the first place. It shouldn't have without the `router-view` component.